# How do I create a string from a block of text that contains the " character

Tags: c#, html, string

I've got a block of html code that includes some form action stuff, which has the " appearing a lot.

Is there a way I can make the entire block into a string?

```
public string methodName()
{
     return @ " text goes here..  blah blah  <p> a bit of html stuff</p>
<form action="www...." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd"
```

I get a lots of angry red underlining from this.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Maybe provide some example of the HTML code you have and explain the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var html = @"<html>
<body>
    <span id=""name""> somethnig more</span>
</body>
</html>";
```

Placing @ before a string means that the contents should not be parsed (\n and other control characters do not work). It also means that the string can span over multiple lines and have " in it, as long as you write "" (only one will be displayed).

Comment: By the way, this is called a Verbatim String Literal.